# Render on Ajax call does not work

Tags: java, jsf-2

In my application, I have the following piece of code:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel for="type" style="font-weight: bold" value="*Type: " />
    <h:selectOneMenu label="type" id="type" binding="#{type}">
        <f:ajax execute="type" render="text article video" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="article" itemLabel="Article" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="video"   itemLabel="Video" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <p:message for="type" />

    <h:outputText id="text" value="#{type.value}" />

    <h:panelGrid id="article" rendered="#{type.value == 'article'}" >
        ...
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid id="video" rendered="#{type.value == 'video'}" >
        ...
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

When I choose an option from the menu, I am sure that the Ajax call was fired because the `<h:outputText>` was rendered with `type.value` correctly. However, none of the `<h:panelGrid>` was rendered.

I'd be very grateful if you could tell me how I should tackle this problem.

Best regards,

James Tran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript/Ajax cannot update HTML elements which are not rendered by JSF. Wrap it in a component which is *always* rendered and then update it instead.

```html
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel for="type" style="font-weight: bold" value="*Type: " />
    <h:selectOneMenu label="type" id="type" binding="#{type}">
        <f:ajax execute="type" render="text grids" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="article" itemLabel="Article" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="video"   itemLabel="Video" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <p:message for="type" />

    <h:outputText id="text" value="#{type.value}" />

    <h:panelGroup id="grids">
        <h:panelGrid id="article" rendered="#{type.value == 'article'}" >
            ...
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid id="video" rendered="#{type.value == 'video'}" >
            ...
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```